# Backreferences in awk range pattern

Tags: awk, backreference

I have a script that I put useful tips in, which allows me to remind myself of various things that I frequently forget. It currently looks like this (but with more useful tips):

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}/^.*'$1'.*:$/,/^$/' <<'_EOF'

tip_header:
  tip1:
    actual tip
  <-- white space to here
  tip2:
    another tip
  <-- white space to here
  something:
    else with \weird $characters^~

another_header:
  tip1:
    tip1 for another_header

_EOF
```

I then call `tips tip_header` to print out everything between `tip_header:` and the empty line before `another_header:` (the line before `tip2:` has whitespace, so is not empty) or `tips tip1` to print out from each of the `tip1:` lines to the next empty line.

I would like to change the awk expression so that the `endpat` matches the first blank line with the same indentation as that found in `begpat`, so that calling `tips tip1` doesn't also print out `tip2`.
Something like:

`awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}/^([[:blank:]]*).*'$1'.*:$/,/^\1$/' <<'_EOF'`

but that doesn't work (I'm not sure how/if one can use backreferences in awk or variants thereof). I'm not opposed to switching out awk with something else that can do multi-line pattern matching.

Edit:
Current output of running `tips tip1` is

```
brett@brett:~/tmp$ ./tips tip1
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip2:
    another tip

  something:
    else with \weird $characters^~

  tip1:
    tip1 for another_header
```

Desired output is

```
brett@brett:~/tmp$ ./tips tip1
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip1:
    tip1 for another_header
```

while still maintaining

```
brett@brett:~/tmp$ ./tips tip_header
tip_header:
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip2:
    another tip

  something:
    else with \weird $characters^~
```

Comment: Though you have tried well for making question clear, could you please post expected output more clearly so that it will be more clear.

Comment: Sounds like re-inventing the wheel. Keep your tips in JSON format, and use jq to parse and extract them

Comment: Even better, assuming this is YAML, use `yq`.

Comment: I do not have the same output when I try your script. I got exactly what you want when running `./tips tip1` but just tip1 info when running `./tips tip_header`

Comment: JSON and YAML aren't installed by default on every linux installation. The intention is to use typically available commands.

Comment: @CorentinLimier Did you add the whitespace back in before the line with `tip2:`? Copying the code above strips out the non-empty line.

Comment: Do you know that your current script gives bad output if, for example, you had a tip12 line somewhere (will give you the block if you search tip1)

Comment: @CorentinLimier Yes, I'm aware of that. I don't always remember what to search for when looking up my saved tips, so partial matches are intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me insist that @tripleee is right imo and you should use proper tools to parse yaml files.

If you really want to use awk, I would do something ugly like this (I tried to do a code that would work on any awk version) :

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v search="$1" -F '' '
    BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}
    (!pos_char)&&($0 ~ (search ".*:")){
    pos_char=1;
        while($pos_char==" "){
            pos_char+=1
        }
        print; next
    } 
    prev_line == "" && NF && pos_char{
        if(NF<pos_char){
            pos_char = 0; next
        }
        for(i=1; i<=pos_char; i++){
            if($i != " "){
                pos_char = 0; next
            }
        }
    }
    pos_char{prev_line=$0;print}
' << '_EOF'

tip_header:
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip2:
    another tip
with carriage return

  something:
    else with \weird $characters^~

another_header:
  tip1:
    tip1 for another_header

_EOF
```

Works only if you use whitespaces to indent.
At least you can remove the ugly whitespace characters on empty lines with this method.

Output :

```
$ ./tips tip
tip_header:
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip2:
    another tip
with carriage return

  something:
    else with \weird $characters^~

  tip1:
    tip1 for another_header

$ ./tips tip_header
tip_header:
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip2:
    another tip
with carriage return

  something:
    else with \weird $characters^~

$ ./tips tip1
  tip1:
    actual tip

  tip1:
    tip1 for another_header

$ ./tips tip2
  tip2:
    another tip
with carriage return
```

Comment: Hmm, close, it misses the real-world case where "`  something:\n    else`" follows `tip2:`, which ought to be included when calling `tips tip` as it's part of the `tip_header:` block. I'll have a play with it tonight to see if I can adjust it to my liking. P.S. As mentioned, I'd rather avoid using yaml or similar, since they aren't always available on base systems, and I'd like the bulk content of the tips to not rely on any special formatting other than indentation and ':'. The tips file started off as just a collection of strings.

Comment: Yes, that mostly seems to do what I want. There's at least one edge case I'm getting, but I don't have time to look into it just now. Thanks.

Comment: @BrettRyland this was updated again to fit your examples

Comment: In the end I switched to using `pcregrep -Mi '(?s)^([ \t]*)\N*?'$1'\N*?:.*?^\1?$\n' <<'_EOF'` instead of awk (yes, it's not installed by default, but it's not uncommon either and the expression is simpler than with awk). I also tried using `grep -Pazo ...`, but couldn't isolate line-beginnings.

Comment: @BrettRyland `the expression is simpler than with awk` really ? :) I find it shorter, not simpler. Good luck with that [regex](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) : `If you write regular expressions that are difficult to read into your codebase, you are doing it wrong.`